# Can't redeem an Ingress Passcode

Tags: ingress

I've gotten a Passcode for Ingress that I know I've never used before. However, when I attempt to add it I'm getting a message `ALREADY_REDEEMED`. What's going on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Passcodes are no longer unlimited.

Sources:

- http://ingress.gproductions.no/i-am-sorry-to-say-that-the-secret-passcodes-are-no-longer-for-unlimited-use-as-they-have-been-shared/
- http://decodeingress.wordpress.com/2012/11/29/ingress-passcodes-change/
- [Ingress support forum](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/ingress-discuss/HgadiWk2lzQ/ugbtcVyJ5iwJ)